# pdb/ipdb swallows exception in debugger in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, python-3.6, pdb, ipdb

*Version info - Python **2.7.15;** Python **3.6.5**;  ipdb==**0.11***

I am not able to access the caught exception `err` in Python 3 inside the debugger (`pdb` or `ipdb`) in the following code. It is not available in `locals` either.

```
try:
    raise ValueError("I am ValueError")
except ValueError as err:
    print("err={}".format(err))
    print("err" in locals())
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace() # not able to acess err in Python 3
```

*OUTPUT:*

***Python 2:***

```
err=I am ValueError
True
--Return--
> test_script.py(6)<module>()->None
-> import pdb; pdb.set_trace() # not able to acess err in Python 3
(Pdb) print("err" in locals())
True
```

***Python 3:***

```
err=I am ValueError
True
--Return--
> test_script.py(6)<module>()->None
-> import pdb; pdb.set_trace() # not able to acess err in Python 3
(Pdb) print("err" in locals())
False  <------------------ BUG??
(Pdb)
```

This happens only inside debugger as `err` is magically restored in `locals` after exiting (or never entering) the debugger.

```
try:
    raise ValueError("I am ValueError")
except ValueError as err:
    print("err={}".format(err))
    print("err" in locals()) # True in both py2/3
    import pdb;
    print("err" in locals()) # True in both py2/3
```

Comment: Assign the exception to a different name inside the `except` block, then you can access it.

Comment: @L3viathan Tried renaming it to err123. Still not able to access it.

Comment: What I mean is: inside the except block, do `err2 = err`

Comment: @L3viathan That surprisingly works! I am not sure about the reason.